# Using [R] to connect to a Web Service

Tags: r

I have a web service, which returns a dataset, and I would like to query it from the [R] statistical package. I'd like to know how (or if) this can be done and also how to load the first datatable, of this dataset, into memory.

Thanks!

EDIT: It is an XML web service

Comment: This may be a question more appropriately asked on the stackoverflow forum, also you may be able to get a more concise answer if you describe what type of file the url is pointing to.

Comment: This question may be more suited for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

If your webservice amounts to calling a URL and getting back XML or json, then you can just use the `XML` or `rjson` packages directly for this.  Possibly with `RCurl` for more elaborate session handling.  See [the `RCurl` paper for an example](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/RCurlJSS.pdf).  You can also look at [our `overflowr` package](http://code.google.com/p/overflowr/) for an example with `rjson`.

*Edit*:

Using `RCurl` is not necessary unless you have a complicated request.  Otherwise, R can natively handle pulling in data over http.  Just pass the url into the function (e.g. read.table).  A simple example:

```
URL <- "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY"
dat <- read.csv(URL)
```

In your case, since your data is XML, you can use the `readLines` function in the same manner.

Have a look at the `getNYTCongress` function in [the `nytR` package](http://code.google.com/p/nytr/source/browse/trunk/R/nyt.congress.R) for an example of reading an XML webservice without `RCurl`.  Also look at [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package).

Comment: Thanks Shane, it's actually an XML web service. I had a quick look at the XML package documentation, am I right in thinking that it just does the parsing? I'm still unsure of how to actually request the data, from the web service. Thanks

Comment: @Matt As Shane wrote; connect with RCurl, get the output and parse it with XML. We would be able to give you the code if you'd give more details about this web service.